# Vue3.js why doesn't my passing of a prop work (or raise an error)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I have a component (a `<select>` menu) which I need to render more than once.

I set it up to receive a prop to determine which of its options is selected in each case (the first menu should have Perth selected and the second one Melbourne):

### App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <SelectMenu :selectedItem="menuASelectedItem" :options="options" />
    <SelectMenu :selectedItem="menuBSelectedItem" :options="options" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SelectMenu from './SelectMenu.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    SelectMenu
},
  data() {
    return {
      menuASelectedItem: 3, 
      menuBSelectedItem: 2, 
      options: [
        { value: '1', label: 'Sydney' },
        { value: '2', label: 'Melbourne' },
        { value: '3', label: 'Perth' },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

and I assumed I could just use that value in the component:

### SelectMenu.vue

```
<template>
  <select v-model="SelectedItem">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    selectedItem: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. Or generate an error. It just doesn't select anything in the menus. By Googling I have figured out that I *can* do this by adjusting the component so that the prop becomes a local variable:

### SelectMenu.vue fixed:

```
<template>
  <select v-model="localSelectedItem"> <!-- localSelectedItem, not SelectedItem -->
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    selectedItem: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() { // data block handles turning selectedItem into localSelectedItem
    return {
      localSelectedItem: this.selectedItem,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

So, I've got my code working, but I need to understand *why* it didn't work the first, more obvious way. Isn't that exactly what props are for? The prop is a variable sent into the component from outside. Why can't it be used directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate the props. In this case, `v-model` enables two-way binding and mutates the prop. To avoid this, you could bind it to a writable computed property that retrieves the prop value. When it is set, emit the value to the parent:

```html
<template>
  <select v-model="localeSelectedItem">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    selectedItem: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  emits: ["update:selectedItem"],
  computed: {
    localeSelectedItem: {
      get() {
        return this.selectedItem;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("update:selectedItem", value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and in the parent bind it as follows :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <SelectMenu v-model:selectedItem="menuASelectedItem" :options="options" />
    <SelectMenu v-model:selectedItem="menuBSelectedItem" :options="options" />
  </div>
</template>
```

You could learn more about this feature in [component v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model)

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't understood that the binding allowed the select menu to mutate the value of the prop, that's the key part which was missing.